# Route Identification Assistance

Tags: help

Is there a way to see what route Tor is taking while I am logged in to a webpage when using the Tor browser? I have thought running a relay search would provide me the information but I have not be able to locate it.

Comment: What do you mean by route? You can check the Tor circuit (the servers that are relaying your data) by clicking the lock icon in the address bar.

Comment: Steve this is exactly what I needed, thank you very much.